# Query single column and return a collection of values instead of complex objects

Tags: java, ormlite

I am in the process of learning about using ORMLite.  I have a specific use case and I am not sure whether the functionality I am looking for exists in ORMLite or if I need to write some extra code on my own.

Here's an example based off the ORMLite documentation. The documentation uses the Account object, and I can do all kinds of queries that return some kind of Collection:

```
// get our query builder from the DAO
QueryBuilder<Account, String> queryBuilder = accountDao.queryBuilder();
// the 'password' field must be equal to "qwerty"
queryBuilder.where().eq(Account.PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME, "qwerty");
// prepare our sql statement
PreparedQuery<Account> preparedQuery = queryBuilder.prepare();
// query for all accounts that have "qwerty" as a password
List<Account> accountList = accountDao.query(preparedQuery);
```

**For my case** I am only interested in a single column from Account - let's pretend it's the 'password' column.  The documentation shows how I can use the `selectColumns(String... columns)` method to select only the columns I want.

> ```
> selectColumns(String... columns)
> ```
>
> Add columns to be returned by the SELECT query and set on any resulting objects. If no columns are selected then all columns are returned by default. For classes with id columns, the id column is added to the select list automagically. All fields not selected in the object with be their default values (null, 0, false, etc.).

**However** this query will still return a collection of Account objects, where nearly ever field contains the default value.  This is obviously one benefit of having automatic garbage collection.  Since my passwords are really Strings and can all be interpreted as such, and I want to pass this information to other classes that really have no concern knowing what an Account is, **what I would really like is a `Collection<String>` instead of a `Collection<Account>`**.

Now it is not my first day programming, so I have various ways of solving this problem for myself.  I could iterate over one collection of Accounts and build a new collection of Strings from it.  A more ORMLite-centric solution which I currently use is to build a custom RowMapper that takes the raw result and returns only the value in the [0] position of the array.

However this makes me wonder if I am missing something, since I am probably not the first person who needs a collection of simple objects instead of a collection of complex objects where all fields except one are null.  I'm wondering if ORMLite provides an even easier way of doing this, but I have not found much in my research.

So that this doesn't become a 'That answer doesnt count, give me another' game, my question is essentially **What built-in functionality for ORMLite provides this convenience?**

Answer (score 0):

> what I would really like is a Collection instead of a Collection.

So most queries done with the DAO returning the entity or collections of the entity that is managed by the DAO.  However, you can certainly use [raw-queries with ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries) and return whatever you'd like.

So you should be able to do something like:

```
GenericRawResults<String> rawResults = orderDao.queryRaw("SELECT qwerty FROM accounts");
for (String result : rawResults) {
   System.out.println("Account qwerty field = " + result);
}
rawResults.close();
```